# how can I change the value of the completedcount in second array to 230?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to update the value of an element in the second array and change it to completed count of first array...

I need to do it using JSON files, and the completed count of first array need to be the value assigned that is 30 sorry for not being clear before..

I've tried using the parseInt().. i'm new to javascript itself...

```
function printjson() {
    var first = new Array(
        {
            projectId: '230',
            title: 'Nikhil',
            status: 'Nikhil',
            seenCount: 0,
            inProgressCount: 0,
            completedCount: 30
        },
        {
            projectId: null,
            title: null,
            status: null,
            seenCount: 0,
            inProgressCount: 0,
            completedCount: 1,
        }
    );
    var second = new Array(
        {
            id: '230',
            name: 'project-qa-test',
            customQuestion: 'What did you get done today?',
            maxSyncItems: null,
            orderIndex: 0,
            hidden: false,
            dones: [],
            unReported: 0,
            seenCount: 0,
            inProgressCount: 0,
            completedCount: 0,
        }
    );
    if (first.projectId == second.Id) {
        second.completedCount = 230;
    }
    console.log(second);
    console.log(second.completedCount);
}
printjson();
```

expected result should be:

```
[
    {
        id: '230',
        name: 'project-qa-test',
        customQuestion: 'What did you get done today?',
        maxSyncItems: null,
        orderIndex: 0,
        hidden: false,
        dones: [],
        unReported: 0,
        seenCount: 0,
        inProgressCount: 0,
        completedCount: 230
    },
]
230
```

but I'm getting:

```
[
    {
        id: '230',
        name: 'project-qa-test',
        customQuestion: 'What did you get done today?',
        maxSyncItems: null,
        orderIndex: 0,
        hidden: false,
        dones: [],
        unReported: 0,
        seenCount: 0,
        inProgressCount: 0,
        completedCount: 0
    },
    completedCount: 230 
]
230
```

Comment: Is it compulsory to use an array? JSON is the best solution for the code that you have shown, Its lightweight and easy to manage in Javascript.

Comment: as I said i'm a beginner in javascript but Yes Json solution will work too thank you

Comment: I'm Glad that it helps!

Comment: Also one suggestion, Whenever you post any query for Javascript, You should provide js fiddle code instead of writing here. It will be easy for anyone to view/run/modify your code and provide you a better solution.

Comment: Will keep in mind from next time thanks.

Comment: How can it be done using JSON???

Comment: Before answering this question, I just wanted to know that why you are using an array here and how you are going to use these arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since *first* and *second* are arrays, you have to use proper indexes to get/set the object properties.

Try:

```
if (first[0].projectId == second[0].id){
  second[0].completedCount = 230;
}
```

```js
function printjson()
{
  var first=new Array( 
  { 
    projectId: '230',
    title: 'Nikhil',
    status: 'Nikhil',
    seenCount: 0,
    inProgressCount: 0,
    completedCount: 30 
  },
  { 
    projectId: null,
    title: null,
    status: null,
    seenCount: 0,
    inProgressCount: 0,
    completedCount: 1 ,
  }
  );
  var second=new Array(
    {
      id: '230',
      name: 'project-qa-test',
      customQuestion: 'What did you get done today?',
      maxSyncItems: null,
      orderIndex: 0,
      hidden: false,
      dones: [],
      unReported: 0,
      seenCount: 0,
      inProgressCount: 0,
      completedCount: 0, 
    } 
  );
  if (first[0].projectId == second[0].id){
    second[0].completedCount = 230;
  }
  console.log(second);
  console.log(second[0].completedCount);
}
printjson();
```

Comment: Yes, mine was an incomplete answer, I deleted mine in favor of yours.

Comment: How to achieve the same using the JSON files? as jayesh said JSON would be easier so I'm curious now... Thanks in advance...

Comment: @NooruddinSaheb, to be honest, I am not clear about his solution.....thanks

Comment: how can I achieve the same using JSON any Idea?

Comment: @NooruddinSaheb, you have arrays of JSON, as far as I know there is no way you can do it without using index.

Comment: if i remove the array and use json file instead?

Comment: @NooruddinSaheb, do you mean json object by *json file*?....  in that case you do not have to use index, simply *obj.propertyName* is enough....